# Python Selenium - Looking for locator to extract only partial element in a single div tag

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors, ui-automation

I need an xpath or any equivalent locator which will fetch me only the partial element with text "EXTEND ALL"
, problem is that the div tag element has 2 text sentences wrapped inside

```
<div _ngcontent-xyu-tt17="" class="tiles-tx">
EXTEND ALL 
<span _ngcontent-xyu-tt17="" 
class="tiles-tag ng-star-inserted">FLASH TO ALL</span><!----></div>
```

Tried below xpath's but it returns me the entire element with text " EXTEND ALL FLASH TO ALL"

```
//div[contains(text(),'EXTEND ALL')]

//div[contains(text(),'EXTEND ALL')]/text() - This xpath works in DOM but throws invalid selector when used with selenium
```

Below is the complete xpath pointing specifically to 'EXTEND ALL'

```
/html/body/app/layout/div/mat-container/mat-content/main/div/app-display/div/a[1]/div/div[2]/text()
```